# Return URL query into post shortcode from functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am able to get the shortcode to return the string 'evs' inline in post [ when I plug that in to return ] but unable to return the post thumb url, using the same shortcode from functions.php

What am I doing wrong here:

```
    function thumburl_func( $atts ){
        
        $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('large');
//      $eva = 'evs';
        return strval($url);
    }
    add_shortcode( 'thumburl', 'thumburl_func' );
```

Been stuck on this for ages now - please save my week !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but you are using [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) incorrectly.

The size of the image you want is the *second* argument into the function, the first argument is the post id. Although the post id is optional, if you want to pass in the size, you need include something as the first argument.

If you are in the Wordpress "loop" and the global `$post` is set up, you can simply pass in `null` e.g.

```
$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'large');
```

However, as this is for a shortcode, the best option is to explicitly pass in the post id - this means the shortcode will work even outside the loop (e.g. in a widget).

```
function thumburl_func( $atts ){
    // 1. get the post id of the current post
    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

    // 2. pass the post is into get_the_post_thumbnail_url
    $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'large');

    return $url;
}
add_shortcode( 'thumburl', 'thumburl_func' );
```

Comment: You absolute legend @FluffyKitten - nailed it ! Thanks so much mate...

Comment: @Casual-T Glad it worked! If the answer helped, you should consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved and so that other users with the same problem know this might help them too. Plus we both get rep points :)

Comment: Aah Roger that ! Thanks again buddy